# MCAPI.class.php showing some error

Tags: functions, errors, api, theme-review

Theme Check Plugin is throwing some errors →

```
WARNING: fsockopen was found in the file inc/widgets/MCAPI.class.php possible file operations.
Line 2862: $sock = fsockopen('ssl://'.$host, 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
Line 2864: $sock = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

reference link →
https://github.com/rainlab/mailchimp-plugin/blob/master/vendor/MCAPI.class.php

Is there a function in WordPress to replace this and make it look like WordPress and remove the error w/o making any changes in the theme or website functionality.

Comment: Why is the **theme** check scanning your plugins?

Comment: It is in the theme. MCAPI.class.php is included in my theme. I am not using that plugin, but just the MCAPI.class.php